# evaluating javascript base10 to base2 conversion function

Tags: javascript, testing, binary, numbers

I wrote a simple function to turn a number that is in base 10 into a binary number. The function I've written is my best attempt using the simple tools I know of. I've looked up other ways of how to do this on this website and I haven't understood a good deal of it. I'm sure the function I've written is very strange but it *seems* to do the trick.

Here is a jsfiddle showing it in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/unpkt48e/

And here is the function code:

```
var toBinary = function(x) {

  x = parseInt(x);

  if (x < 0) {
    var k = '-' 
    x = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2));    
  }

  if (x == 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  var y = x;
  var g = [];

  while (Math.log2(y) >= 0) {
    var n = parseInt(Math.log2(y)); 
    g.push(n+1);
    y = y - Math.pow(2, n);
  }

  var binArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < g[0]; i++) {
    binArray.push(0);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
    binArray[binArray.length-g[i]] = 1;
  }

  var binary = binArray.join("");
  return (k || "") + binary;

};
```

I don't have a lot of tools yet for evaluating this so my question is as follows:

What this function returns *looks* right, but how can I make sure what I'm getting is actually a binary number and not just a string that looks like a binary number. Am I missing a few key pieces? Or is my approach a dead end?

An additional question: Is there a built-in function in JS to do this for me? Mostly, this is a learning exercise for me so I'm still interested in producing a base10 to base2 number converting function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) numObj.toString(base) pass base value as parameter , added Demo

```js
var input = document.getElementById("decimal");
input.addEventListener("input", getBinary);

function getBinary() {
  var decimal = document.getElementById("decimal").value;
  var binary = Number(decimal).toString(2);
  document.getElementById("binary").innerHTML = binary;
};
```

```css
body {
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
}
p { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<body>
<p>Enter a number here:</p>
<input id="decimal"><br><br>

<p>This is that number but in binary:</p><br>
<p id="binary" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 20px;min-width :100px"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: In what way can I compare the output of my function against the approach you've described? Is there some way to distinguish, for example, the string 101 (one zero one) from the number 101 (one hundred and one) and the binary number 101 (5 in base10)?

Comment: @Jozurcrunch By knowing which base it is written in. No, otherwise `101` is not distinguishable from `101`. If you want to annotate the number representation with the used base though, it's common to use it as a suffix: `101₁₀ = 1100101₂`, `101₂ = 5₁₀`

Comment: I've tried using some bitwise operators on a few of the outputs, and some work. But if I try g = toBinary(5) = 101, and h = toBinary(7) = 111, then do XOR (g ^ h) the result is '10', when I know it should be '010'. Does this speak to a problem in my code?